# FTP error on getting and putting files

Tags: java, networking, ftp, port, firewall

Good day SO people!

I have an ftp issue. We've set up an ftp server in Windows and it is being accessed programatically using java. The client is a linux machine with no ftp installed in it.

For Client A, the process of getting and putting is successful.
For Client B, the process of getting and putting failed.

I've checked the firewalls of Client A, Client B, and the FTP Server.
I've checked the ports of the FTP Server.

Questions:

Should a client have an ftp installed? Please shed some light on this because both clients A and B have no ftp installed in them yet the other successfully finishes the process and the other fails.

What could be the cause of this? I am running out of ideas because I've searched the net for probable causes. Active vs Passive FTP, ports, firewalls, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you accessing ftp in Java?  Which libraries and/or methods are you using?  Can you paste some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: needn't to install ftp server in your client host. you say you write a java ftp client program, It's enought.

Q2: your should post the error code when client B is put/get fail. Does client B login ftp server success?

I suggest you have better set your java ftp client program to use PASV mode.